# LCS: Will tie-breakers count in the Fantasy League?

Tags: league-of-legends, competitive-gaming, fantasy-lcs

With the NALCS tie-breakers coming up, I'm wondering. Will the tie-breakers get me points or are they not counted in the results?

Note: Was not sure if this question belongs here, but fantasy LCS is a 'game' to some extent, and it's ESports. I do think it's the best place I could post this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, tie-breakers do not earn points in the fantasy league according to a Rioter, who I asked in a private chat.

Comment: "according to rioter" i asked in private chat does not appear as a valid source. Rioters can also be wrong.